# Python 2.7 (socket) - how to continue on the next port if socket.error occurred on previous port

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, port

I am working on simple scanning script, which scan all open ports from the list of the IPs and check their banners.

I have a problem, when `socket.error` occur on one of the port, the script exit and does not continue with banner grabbing on next port and also on next IP from the list.

How can I modify my script so that if `socket.error` occurs it will continue to scan and not exit?

```
print "+" * 40
starting_time = time.time()  
print " Scanning started at %s" % (time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p"))
print "+" * 40
print "+" * 40

ip_parts1 = host.split('.')  
h = ip_parts1[0] + '.' + ip_parts1[1] + '.' + ip_parts1[2] + '.' + ip_parts1[3]

print "\033[1;31m"
lst1 = map_network0()
try:
    for h in lst1[:]:
        for port in range(1, 1024):
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            result = sock.connect_ex((h, port))

            if result == 0:
                byte = str.encode("Server:\r\n")
                sock.send(byte)
                ans = sock.recv(512)
                socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
                print h, ("......port " + '{0}'.format(port) + "/Open/" + '{0}'.format(ans))
            sock.close()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("Scanner aborted")
    sys.exit()

except socket.gaierror:
    print ('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
    sys.exit()

except socket.error:
    print ("Couldn't connect to server")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: By pulling in the Exception handling INTO the loop.

Comment: @deets I also tried to add exception in the loop, but unfortunately without success

Comment: But that’s not what you show. What you show can’t possibly work. Pulling it in can if you don’t make other mistakes.

Comment: this is not the whole script, only the part, but the problem ocurre here. the script works and I get results for many ports, but when error ocurre script exit and does not scan further on next ports and ip

Comment: Again, the answer doesn't change: if you handle errors *outside* the loop, there is no possible way for the script to continue *with* the loop. That's just how Python works.

Comment: yeah, I know that I need to handle error exception inside the loop. I tried but without success. can you suggest me where and what exactly should I add in the loop?

Comment: Literally put the try excepts *inside* the inner loop. That is all. Of course you can then go wild regarding re-trying etc, but that is all.

Comment: @deets I finally made it, with adding exception into the loop. Thank you for help and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I made it. I add exception into the loop. So, now if error occur, it will pass the port and continue with scanning on next port.

```
try:                                                                                            
    for h in lst1[:]:                                                                           
        for port in range(1, 1024):                                                             
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)                            
            result = sock.connect_ex((h, port))                                                 

            try:                                                                                
                if result == 0:                                                                 
                    byte = str.encode("Server:\r\n")                                            
                    sock.send(byte)                                                             
                    socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)                                                 
                    ans = sock.recv(512)                                                        
                    print h, ("......port " + '{0}'.format(port) + "/Open/" + '{0}'.format(ans))
                    sock.close()                                                                
            except socket.error:                                                                
                print                                                                           
                print ("Couldn't connect to server " + h + " port: "'{0}'.format(port))         
                pass                                                                            

except KeyboardInterrupt:                                                                       
    print ("Scanner aborted")                                                                   
    sys.exit()                                                                                  

except socket.gaierror:                                                                         
    print ('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')                                           
    sys.exit()                                                                                  

except socket.error:                                                                            
    print ("Couldn't connect to server")                                                        
    pass
```